# NSMutableArray with Integer

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have this mutable array:

```
myIntegers = [NSMutableArray array];

[myIntegers addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexDelete - 1]];

NSLog (@"Array: %@", myIntegers);
```

If I execute the code twice, with indexDelete first being 1 and then 2, I get this result:

```
Array: (
1
)
```

and then:

```
Array: (
2
)
```

But I would like to store both numbers like this:

```
Array: (
1
2
)
```

Why is it not adding, but replacing the object??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're creating a new empty array every time that code executes, on this line:

```
myIntegers = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Adding an object to an empty array always leads to there being one object in that array.